# Is it possible to encode a file as a Data URI in Java?

Tags: java, file, data-uri, data-url

I have the need to encode a file as a data URI in Java, is it possible for me to retrieve this in the following format?

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA==
```

I've been looking for something like it, but had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a utility function specifically for creating it, but it should be as simple as:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

byte[] toEncode = { 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc };
Base64 base64NoLineWrap = new Base64(0);
String encodedData = base64NoLineWrap.encodeBase64String(toEncode);
String dataUri = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + encoded;
```